# TransactionScope TransactionInDoubtException in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, transactionscope

The following code is part of my business layer:

```
   public void IncrementHits(int ID)
    {
        using (var context = new MyEntities())
        {
            using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
            {
                Models.User userItem = context.User.First(x => x.IDUser == ID);
                userItem.Hits++;
                try
                {
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    transaction.Complete();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    transaction.Dispose();
                    throw;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Sometimes (once or twice a week) I get a `TransactionInDoubtException`. Stacktrace:

```
at System.Transactions.TransactionStateInDoubt.EndCommit(InternalTransaction tx) 
at System.Transactions.CommittableTransaction.Commit() 
at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.InternalDispose() 
at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.Dispose()
```

As far as I know, the default isolation level is serializable, so there should be no problem with this atomic operation. (Assuming there is no timeout occuring because of a write lock)

How can I fix my problem?

Comment: And what is the database? If sql server, then which version?

Comment: Why the bounty? Have you tried Azhar's suggestion (I suggest the same)?

Comment: @SimonMourier but will it make any difference? Dispose will rollback transaction anyway if Complete has not been called.

Comment: At least you should be able to retry the SaveChanges() call.

Comment: Think of a transaction as an object with a nullable boolean state (and everyone who has that transaction reference can change that flag).
If nobody changes this state, it stays null, if someone calls Commit() the state becomes true.
If someone calls Rollback() the state becomes false.

Eventually the transaction will finish and the state will be used to determine its outcome.
Since you do nothing, the state was null, which is what's is "in doubt" transaction at that moment.

Only transactions with a true state will eventually commit.

Comment: Plus, as is, your try catch is useless, as Dispose() will be done by the using, even if an exception occurs (that's the whole point of using)

Comment: @SimonMourier *Since you do noting* - What do you mean? Connections are opened and closed within the scope of the transaction, `transaction.Complete()` should commit the transaction alright.

Comment: Yes, you do nothing when an exception occurs.

Comment: @SimonMourier They don't do "nothing"! And *if* they did the TS wouldn't throw an exception. Of course not.

Comment: @citronas Why do you use a TS at all? In the code you show it isn't necessary because `SaveChanges` manages its own transaction. If in reality you do more within a TS you should show the actual code.

Comment: @GertArnold intention of this code, as I understand, is to safely increment `userItem.Hits`. For that reason, OP wraps both select (`First`) and update (`SaveChanges`) into one transaction with serializable level.

Comment: @SimonMourier that's just not true. If you dispose `TransactionScope` and it was not commited (`Complete` was not called) - it will be rollbacked for you. Calling `Rollback` is not required. Of course in OPs case the whole try-catch is useless, but that's another story, and should not affect behavior.

Comment: @Evk That's probably right. I try to get some feedback from OP because their lack of responsiveness (already after your first comment) makes the bounty pretty useless.

Comment: @Evk23: Azure hosted SQL Server, 12.0.2000.8. Yes, my intention is to prevent lost updates. Based on my theoretical knowledge of database transactions from a university course, I assumed the SQL server scheduler would wait until the particular row can be locked and then updated. I assumed that multiple simultaneous calls with this code would enforce a serial execution of my transactions. But this is not what happens, otherwise I would not get any exceptions. How do you suggest would be the best practice to increment the counter while avoiding lost updates? I'm open to suggestions ;-)

Comment: Did you consider to replace this whole thing with simple "update User set Hits = Hits + 1 where IDUser = @id" sql query?

Comment: @Evk Oh, no I actually did not ^^ Your query would make the update atomic. I'm still wondering how I can achieve a serial transaction execution with the objects from EntityFramework (and thus avoid writing SQL code manually). For more complex business logic where multiple tables should be updated atomically, I would assume that EF somehow provides a transactiontional execution. I hope that my words are understandable

Comment: Well it provides transactional execution by running `SaveChanges` inside one transaction. So if you modify many entities in different tables, then call `SaveChanges` - all those modifications (updates\inserts) will run inside one transaction (though it's isolation level will be default isolation level of database, which is unlikely to be serializable). So if default behavior doesn't suite your needs - using explicit `TransactionScope` is a good way to go.

Comment: AFAIK, `TransactionInDoubtException` only occurs when MSDTC is involved. Is this really all code that causes the exception? Also, this is a way to get deadlocks, although in that case I wouldn't expect this exception. Is there an inner exception?

Comment: just a side not: in your code, do not try-cath at all. This is exactly why we use 'using transactionScope' - to have a syntax sugar for try-finally. And this hidden try-finally will take care about calling dispose regardless of exception. So, your try-catch is redundant here.

Answer (score 4):

Use transaction.Rollback instead of transaction.Dispose

If you have a transaction in a pending state always rollback on exception.

Comment: Yeah makes sense. But do you have any idea why I even get an exception in the first place? Or is this exception not my 'real' exception? I'm confused

Comment: If an exception occurs in your code and the transaction is pending,  you're not gracefully exiting from the transaction. You are disposing the transaction in a limbo kind of state. That is why it is saying that the transaction state is in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

msdn says "if the transaction manager loses contact with the subordinate participant after sending the Single-Phase Commit request but before receiving an outcome notification, it has no reliable mechanism for recovering the actual outcome of the transaction. Consequently, the transaction manager sends an In Doubt outcome to any applications or voters awaiting informational outcome notification"

Please look into these links

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc229955.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.ienlistmentnotification.indoubt(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Add finally block to dispose the transaction. And set some status = true if you commit the transactions.

Check same in finally block and if status is true then don't rollback otherwise rollback and dispose the transaction.

Answer (score -1):

Would it behave properly if you moved your try/catch to include the using directive for the Transaction scope? The using directive should implicitly call Dispose for you (so doing it explicitly seems redundant) and then you can throw the exception. This is what I see implement in examples from MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx